# Rearrange Text blocks such that each ends with a complete sentence

Tags: python, string, text

I have three sets of text blocs (actually many more...) which show part of a complete text. However the partitioning of the original text was not done correctly as some sentences were split between two text blocks.

```
text1 = {"We will talk about data about model specification parameter \
estimation and model application and the context where we will apply \
the simple example.Is an application where we would like to analyze \
the market for electric cars because"};

text2 = {"we are interested in the market of electric cars.The choice \
that we are interested in is the choice of each individual to \
purchase an electric car or not And we will see how"};

text3 = {"to address this question. Furthermore, it needs to be noted that this is only a model text and there is no content associated with it. "};
```

For instance `text2` starts with "we are interested in the market of electric cars." This is an incomplete first sentence, which actually started in text block 1 (see last sentence there).

I want to make sure that each text block ends with a complete sentence. So I want to move incomplete first sentences to the last text block.  For instance here, the result would be:

```
 text1corr = {"We will talk about data about model specification parameter \
    estimation and model application and the context where we will apply \
    the simple example.Is an application where we would like to analyze \
    the market for electric cars because we are interested in the market of electric cars."};

text2corr = {"The choice that we are interested in is the choice of each individual to purchase an electric car or not And we will see how to address this question."};

text3corr = {"Furthermore, it needs to be noted that this is only a model text and there is no content associated with it. "};
```

**How can I do it in Python ? Is this even possible ?**

Comment: does a  full stop indicates the end of the sentence?

Comment: @paradox Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `zip_longest()` to iterate over string pairs:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import re

l = [text1, text2, text3]
new_l = []

for i, j in zip_longest(l, l[1:], fillvalue=''):
    # remove leading and trailing spaces
    i, j = i.strip(), j.strip()
    # remove leading half sentence
    if i[0].islower():
        i = re.split(r'[.?!]', i, 1)[-1].lstrip()
    # append half sentence from next string
    if i[-1].isalpha():
        j = re.split(r'[.?!]', j, 1)[0]
        i = f"{i} {j}."
    new_l.append(i)

for i in new_l:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
We will talk about data about model specification parameter estimation and model application and the context where we will apply the simple example.Is an application where we would like to analyze the market for electric cars because we are interested in the market of electric cars.
The choice that we are interested in is the choice of each individual to purchase an electric car or not And we will see how to address this question.
Furthermore, it needs to be noted that this is only a model text and there is no content associated with it.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What does  zip_longest do ?  Would you mind to add some comments to your code to get the general idea ? Thanks.

Comment: @james  Your are welcome. `zip_longest` generates pairs: `text1, text2; text2, text3; text3, ‘‘`. I added some comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
text1 = "We will talk about data about model specification parameter \
estimation and model application and the context where we will apply \
the simple example.Is an application where we would like to analyze \
the market for electric cars because"

text2 = "we are interested in the market of electric cars.The choice \
that we are interested in is the choice of each individual to \
purchase an electric car or not And we will see how"

text3 = "to address this question. Furthermore, it needs to be noted that this is only a model text and there is no content associated with it. "
```

---

```
textList = [text1,text2,text3]
```

---

```
corrected_list = []
prev_incomplete_sentece = ''
for index , text in enumerate(textList):
    if(len(prev_incomplete_sentece) > 0):
        corrected_text =  text[len(prev_incomplete_sentece) + 1:]
    else:
        corrected_text = text
    if(index +1 < len(textList)):
        corrected_text += ' '+ textList[index+1].split('.')[0]
        prev_incomplete_sentece = textList[index+1].split('.')[0]
    corrected_list.append(corrected_text)
```

---

Output:

```
['We will talk about data about model specification parameter estimation and model application and the context where we will apply the simple example.Is an application where we would like to analyze the market for electric cars because we are interested in the market of electric cars',
 'The choice that we are interested in is the choice of each individual to purchase an electric car or not And we will see how to address this question',
 ' Furthermore, it needs to be noted that this is only a model text and there is no content associated with it. ']
```

Comment: It splits the first block after "example". Please have a look at the expected outcome in my question. It is unfortunately not the same.

Comment: do you want exact output or do you want to split text according to full sentences?

Comment: I  would like the exact output. Each text block should end with a complete sentence. If this is not the case, then the remaining part of the sentence should be taken from the next text block.

Comment: great answer! Thanks a lot!